# AngularJS 1.x interface/API for Open Street Maps

Tags: gratis, angularjs

For some years, I used [NgMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) for Angular 1.x (note that I require a solution for v1.x; I am not going to learn TypeScript and use Angular v2 or greater).

It seems that last year Google changed the API to require a key ***and*** a credit card number. I am having trouble getting the key to work on both localhost and my sever, so maybe it is time to switch to OSM.

Does anyone know of a good, gratis,  library, or set of directives,etc, for OSM and AngularJS v1.x?

Answer (score 0):

I went for [LeafletJs](https://leafletjs.com/), which is free and extremely well documented and easy to use with Open Street maps (and others).

StackOverflow currently has 27,500+ questions tagged Leaflet, so you cna be sure of support.

I have been using it almost since I posted this question (ought to have answered sooner) and already have a bunch of projects under my belt.